# Formula isn't Correctly Calculating

Tags: java, equation, modulo

I am trying to figure out why the following is not correctly calculating

```
 x = Math.pow(w,e);
```

When I calculate it in Java, I get 1075, but I am supposed to get 779.

```
   int e = 17;
   int w = 803;
   int n = 2773;
   double x = 0;
        x = Math.pow(w,e) % n;
        System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: 800^17 is too large. Consider using BigInteger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double` floating point numbers have 53 bits of precision, which is not enough to store the exact value of a huge number like 803<sup>17</sup>. To do modular exponentiation in Java, you can use the [`modPow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)) method on `BigInteger`s.

Answer (score 2):

As (803^17) is a very big number so you have to use the BigInteger datatype for the variables used here instead of int or double datatype. We cannot convert the integer or double variable to a BigInteger variable.

So, the program will be :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class JavaPow {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger("17");
        BigInteger w = new BigInteger("803");
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger("2773");
        BigInteger x;
        x = w.modPow(e,n);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```